# Restrict user access to app functionalities

Tags: sapui5

I have a custom ui5 app that has some options ( for example it has a list to view items and options, to edit price, description, etc ) . Its now required that only certain users access to edit the information, so I think using some decorator for that button would be the best idea.
However it doesn't seem possible with ui5, is there any way to achieve this? I've tried using neo-app.json but I think its not suitable. Thanks

Comment: just a simple if else condition would do that...depending upon the user show/hide the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

**If your app is a standalone HTML5 app:**

- First step is to have an IDP, and user-federating system, on your platform. Are you using SAP Cloud Platform? It has all the options available for user management. If not, you're going to have to manage it some other way - using KeyCloak or whatever your favourite user federating system is.
- Second step is to configure your backend API to use the same user management system. Typically, if you're developing on SCP, then your backend is also exposed on SCP, and then it's easy to use the same user management system. This needs to use the user federation system defined in your platform.
- Third step is to configure which tiles are visible by which roles. On SCP, this happens in the Fiori Launchpad; you can personalise each tile there.

**If your frontend app lives on the server side, similar to JSPs:**

- Implement a login page for your application and have your server manage the authentication process.
- Based on the logged in user's role, you can have several different index.html files, which load different tiles.

Note that I have rarely used this second approach; that's not what UI5 is designed for, and it's not as clean or easy. The framework is clearly designed with the first approach in mind. It will be a fairly seamless process if you're using SCP to develop your app.

Let me know if I can clarify this further, or if you have any additional questions.

Comment: thanks ! Its a standalone app that will run on SCP, not going to deploy it in the launchpad and we have cloud identity configured to login users. The restriction I think that has to be inside the app to display some information/buttons according to users role. In the neo-json I can restrict paths, but not specific functions